# SQL Server : concatenation and sum totals from tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my first stored procedure, not sure what I am doing. Maybe you can teach me something.

I am trying to create a procedure called `SPGET_CUSTOMER_BILL` and it is supposed to bring up the name of the customer concatenated first name and last name along with the sum of numbers from 2 different tables which would be their total bill.

I have these 4 tables:

- `SALON_CUSTOMER`: CUST_ID, STY_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME
- `APPOINTMENT`: APPT_TIME, CUST_ID, STY_ID, SERVICE_ID, PROD_NUM
- `PRODUCT`: PROD_NUM, PROD_TYPE, PROD_NAME, PROD_VENDOR, PRICE
- `SERVICE_`: SERVICE_ID, SERVICE_DESC, EST_TIME, PRICE

What I need to do is sum the `PRICE` from `PRODUCT` table and the `PRICE` from the `SERVICE_` table for each appointment/customer and list that along with their first and last name concatenated in the first column.

Here is what the result needs to look like:

```
CUSTOMER_NAME   TOTAL_BILL
-----------------------------    
JOHN DOE           45.64
JANE DOE           52.64
```

I am probably way off, but here is my code right now, its pretty jumbled by now I've been messing around with it too much.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPGET_CUSTOMER_BILL
AS 
    SELECT 
       RTRIM(FIRST_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(LAST_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_NAME,
       SUM(ISNULL(P.PRICE, 0) = ISNULL(S.PRICE, 0) TOTAL_BILL
    FROM 
       APPOINTMENT A
    INNER JOIN 
       SALON_CUSTOMER ON SALON_CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = A.CUST_ID
    INNER JOIN 
       PRODUCT P ON A.PROD_NUM = P.PROD_NUM
    INNER JOIN 
       SERVICE_ S ON S.SERVICE_ID = A.SERVICE_ID;
```

If I split them up, they work fine. I just can't get them to work together. If you could teach me a little something about what i am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without understanding your data, (assuming your logic and joins are correct) it looks like you just need to group by the computed customer name go get the totals. This will return all customers - you might want to add a `CustomerId` parameter to the PROC and then add a WHERE filter to it?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SPGET_CUSTOMER_BILL
AS 
    SELECT RTRIM(FIRST_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(LAST_NAME) AS CUSTOMER_NAME,
      SUM(ISNULL(P.PRICE, 0)) TOTAL_BILL
    FROM APPOINTMENT A
      INNER JOIN SALON_CUSTOMER ON SALON_CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = A.CUST_ID
      INNER JOIN PRODUCT P ON A.PROD_NUM = P.PROD_NUM
      INNER JOIN SERVICE_ S ON S.SERVICE_ID = A.SERVICE_ID
    -- WHERE?
    GROUP BY RTRIM(FIRST_NAME) + ' ' + RTRIM(LAST_NAME);
```

Comment: This actually worked just as I needed it to without a WHERE filter. all i needed to do was add in the + ISNULL(S.PRICE, 0)) to this code and its perfect. Thanks a lot for you help, I understand it better now.